# running sudo command in ruby

Tags: ruby, deployment, web-deployment

I would like to build ruby git deploy script. A server that gets json data from gitlab hooks and updates project files on the server where it is running.

projects are a mix of `laravel` / `wordpress` / `joomla` / `ror`.

My problem is `www-data` owned laravel wp and joomla destinations.

I usually update these directories via `sudo -u www-data git pull`

SO rvm needs sudo privileges. This in theory could cause trouble on production server.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use rvm in a way that needs root privileges.  Install rvm for www-data (and any other users that need it), and to avoid confusion, uninstall the system-wide (root) rvm.  Your deployment script can then install gems as the www-data user, without needing sudo.